# Check if a socket disconnected in C, without select()

Tags: c, sockets

Is there any way to check if a socket has disconnected on the remote end without select() in C?

The reason I don't want to use select() is that in the case that my buffers are full, there may be data available for reading on the socket that I am intentionally ignoring and a select(readfds=[socket_fd]) would always return immediately letting me know.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a blocking read() function call on the socket, and it returns the integer value 0, that means the socket connection is closed.

```
while ( n = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) ) {
     //use buffer contents
}
```

This loop will continue while data is being sent from the other end.

Answer (score 1):

So use `poll()` instead, setting `events` to the things you care about and checking the results in `revents`. FYI, you can call `select()` or `poll()` without harming the sockets or changing their buffers.

Comment: I have some problems when using poll() like this, revents never contains POLLHUP when the socket hangs up, just POLLIN which can't be true.

Comment: See http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2001/06/poll.html for some nice info about this issue.